# Multiple posible conditions realm query

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

Say I have 3 choices of sorting.

**Dog class have 3 kinds**

- Bulldog
- Poodle
- Pug

Base on 3 selection, I guess I have 9 combination?(not sure). Do you have to use a **lot of if statements to sort and query the result**?  Say on the example I want to **display** Bulldog and poodle? or **If anything is not selected** I will have to **show all of the list** of dog registered. What if I have 10 selections each with different combination selection. Do you use if statements for all of those? That is like 100 possible combination. Is there any other way to query realm with other possible combinations? With so many kinds of dogs out there. It would be hard to do if statements and try to hard code all possible combinations

Scenario:

I have a dog class

```
class Dog : RealmObject(){
 var name:String
 var kind:String

}
```

now on my recycler view I have a **list of dogs** inputted by people. In that people can browse the dog. They can query what type. **Say they want the recycler view to show a poodle and a pug** or a **husky and a poodle**. They would just check the menu item checkbox and then voila the result of husky and poodle is shown

Edit :

I tried using **or** and **and** logical operators. But I can't figure out how to do the possible combinations. All I got is doing if statements which would be a lot since I have 5 selection choices and 25 possible combination

Edit :
 This is the exact problem on my part. The multiple possible combination query on realm.

My goal is to minimise the coding of if statements  by relying on realm query if it's possible

If I hard coded the combination it would look something like this

```
if(pug && husky){
 val result = realm.where(Dog::class.java).equalto("kind","husky").equalto("kind",pug").findall()
}
.
.
.
.
. a lot of ifs
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. What are you trying to query, what are you expecting, what do you get, etc.

Comment: I tried using or and and logical operators. But I can't figure out how to do the possible combinations. All I got is doing if statements which would be a lot since I have 5 selection choices and 25 possible combination

Comment: What are the fields? What are the models? What are "the possible combinations"? What is your goal?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I've added my scenario.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce my goal is to minimise the coding of if statements if possible by relying on realm query if its possible

Comment: Im not sure who voted to close it, but I hope I got my point right.

Comment: the first person did, and then you fixed your question, good job :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) if you want to support multiple field query where query options are built from data in database, you can use `distinct()` and create a `Set<String>`.

```
val kinds = realm.where<Dog>().distinct("kind").findAll().map { it.kind }.toSet()
```

2.) Once you have sets, you can build the queries based on what's in the set.

```
fun filter(realm: Realm, kinds: Set<String>): RealmResults<Dog> { // might wanna introduce a class for the sets
    val query = realm.where<Dog>()
    if(kinds.isNotEmpty()) {
        query.beginGroup()
        kinds.forEachIndexed { index, kind -> 
            if(index != 0) {
                query.or()
            }
            query.equalTo("kind", kind)
        }
        query.endGroup()
    }
    return query.findAll()
}
```

If you want to send in a sort key, that'd just be a `.sort(sortKey)`.

Then as you can see, you can generalize this function:

```
fun filter(realm: Realm, vararg filters: Pair<String, Set<*>>): RealmResults<Dog> { 
    val query = realm.where<Dog>()

    fun applyFilters(query: RealmQuery<Dog>, filterParams: Pair<String, Set<*>>) {
        val (fieldName, filter) = filterParams
        if(filter.isNotEmpty()) {
            query.beginGroup()
            filter.forEachIndexed { index, value -> 
                if(index != 0) {
                    query.or()
                }
                query.equalTo(fieldName, value)
            }
            query.endGroup()
        }
    }

    filters.forEachIndexed { index, filter ->
        if(index != 0) {
            query.or()
        }
        applyFilters(query, filter)
    }

    return query.findAll()
}
```

Where it could be called as

```
val results = filter(realm, 
                "kind" to setOf("Bulldog", "Poodle"), 
                "name" to setOf("George"))
```

But please note that I wrote this just now on a whim so I might have messed up somewhere. I'm not sure if you can use `Set<*>` like that, but `Set<String>` should work just fine in your use-case anyways.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: Hi, I have not accepted the answer yet. Im still trying to figure out why result is 0 whenever I query husky and pug.